# How can I use Get-WmiObject to filter on a processes "command line"

Tags: powershell, windows-7, powershell-2.0, get-wmiobject

Is there a way to specify the `-Filter` parameter, using the WMI Query Language (WQL), of the Get-WmiObject  cmdlet to filter based on the “Command Line” used to invoke the process?  By “Command Line” I mean the “Command Line” that is shown in the Windows Task Manger, Process tab.

I want to get an array of process ids where the command line contains the string `*Dev_SW*`.  I cannot use name because there are will be many process running with the same name that are not equal to the `*Dev_SW*` filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get-WMIObject will make the WMI call to the Class Win32_Process,

Then it will filter it where Command Line is like DEV_SW,

% is wild card in WMI

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "CommandLine LIKE '%Dev_SW%'"
```